# loop does not iterate through all elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm having some trouble with my loop. It doesn't seem to want to iterate through the entire jquery object and check every instance of .box in order to verify the background colors of the columns. The app is a puzzle that is completed when all columns are turned dark. When I click on columns 2, then 4, then 3, there are still two columns, 7 and 9, that are still light, but the program says that the puzzle is complete. I can't figure out what's causing the premature complete when I hit that specific sequence of columns. When those columns become dark through clicking a different sequence of columns the problem does not occur.

Also, I should note that when a column is clicked, it's color is changed and the two columns to the left and right also change their colors from light to dark or vice versa.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Puzzle</h1>
            <p>Goal: make all of the columns dark.</p>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box light"></div>
                <div class="box dark"></div>
                <div class="box light"></div>
                <div class="box dark"></div>
                <div class="box light"></div>
                <div class="box dark"></div>
                <div class="box light"></div>
                <div class="box dark"></div>
                <div class="box light"></div>
                <div class="box dark"></div>
            </div>
            <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
h1, p {
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.box {
    flex: 1;
    margin: 3em .75em;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.light {
    background: rgb(221, 211, 211);
}

.dark {
    background: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
```

And JS:

```
//click on box
$('.box').click(function(){
    //check box color
    var $background = $(this).css('background-color');
    if ($background === 'rgb(51, 51, 51)') {
        //change to light #CCC
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(221, 221, 221)');
    } else {
        //change to dark #333
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(51, 51, 51)');
    }

    if ($(this).is(':not(:first-child)')) {
        var $backgroundLeft = $(this).prev().css('background-color');
        if ($backgroundLeft === 'rgb(51, 51, 51)') {
            //change to light #CCC
            $(this).prev().css('background-color', 'rgb(221, 221, 221)');
        } else {
            //change to dark #333
            $(this).prev().css('background-color', 'rgb(51, 51, 51)');
        }
    }

    //check right box color
    if ($(this).is(':not(:last-child)')) {
        var $backgroundRight = $(this).next().css('background-color');
        if ($backgroundRight === 'rgb(51, 51, 51)') {
            //change to light #CCC
            $(this).next().css('background-color', 'rgb(221, 221, 221)');
        } else {
            //change to dark #333
            $(this).next().css('background-color', 'rgb(51, 51, 51)');
        }
    }

    function isComplete() {
      var failed = false;
      $('.box').each(function(){
        if ($(this).css('background-color') === 'rgb(221, 221, 221)') {
            failed = true;
            return false;
        }
      });
      return (!failed) ? true : false;
    }

    if(isComplete()) {
        alert('Puzzle completed!');
    }
});
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of: you cannot rely on browsers giving back a color string the same way you set it. In other words, `rgb(221, 221, 221)` that you use to *set* a color may be reported as `#DDDDDD` when you examine it later.

Comment: Also, use `$box.each(function() { ... })` to iterate, since you're using jQuery anyway.

Comment: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zfsu3n0c/)** if anyone insists.. ;)

Comment: You don't need `(!failed) ? true : false;` use simply `!failed`.

Comment: Woo-hoo, finished the puzzle @Guruprasad Rao! Thanks.

Comment: Also, in your CSS you have `.light {background: rgb(221, 211, 211);}`, and I believe you intended for it to be `rgb(221, 221, 221)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of checking for background-color, you should try use the `.hasClass()` jQuery function. So check if it has the class `dark` or `light`. But even that is not necessary (check fiddle)

A better check for complete could be:

```
function isComplete() {
    return $('.box').length === $('.box.dark').length;
}
```

For giggles i made my own fiddle as well:

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ayf10xug/5/)

Comment: Thanks for that. I've trimmed down my code with your suggestion and it also works to boot!

Comment: In case you were using my fiddle, I've updated it. There was still a problem with the `isComplete()` function check.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your problem, but you should use the `.toggleClass()` function.

Makes your javascript much simpler

Added PierreDuc's change to the fiddle and it seems to work fine with some limited testing.

https://jsfiddle.net/zfsu3n0c/1/

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    //check box color
    $(this).toggleClass("light dark");

    if ($(this).is(':not(:first-child)')) {
        $(this).prev().toggleClass("light dark");
    }

    //check right box color
    if ($(this).is(':not(:last-child)')) {
        $(this).next().toggleClass("light dark");
    }

    // Use PierreDuc's is complete
    function isComplete() {
      return $('.box').length === $('.box.dark').length;
    }

    if(isComplete()) {
        alert('Puzzle completed!');
    }
});
```